# PyInit already defined - PyBind

Tags: c++, pybind11

I want to build a module for python, and it compiled fine when I had 1 header, 1 cpp file, but I wanted to extend it to 1 header, 2 cpp files, and now I get errors I don't really understand.

My Header (fast_qs_module.h):

```
#ifndef FASTCOSINE_MODULE_INCLUDE_H
#define FASTCOSINE_MODULE_INCLUDE_H

#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <vector>

std::vector<double> get_dwds_distances(std::vector<std::vector<double>> unlabeled, std::vector<std::vector<double>> labeled, double alpha);
std::vector<double> get_euclidian_distances_to_reference(std::vector<std::vector<double>> unlabeled, std::vector<double> reference);

PYBIND11_MODULE(fast_cosine, mod) {
    mod.def("get_dwds_distances", &get_dwds_distances, "Multithreaded DWDS calculations to get the values for each unlabeled sample.");
    mod.def("get_euclidian_distances", &get_euclidian_distances_to_reference, "Multithreaded Euclidian distance calculations to get the values for each unlabeled sample.");
}

#endif  // FASTCOSINE_MODULE_INCLUDE_H
```

One cpp file:

```
#include [...]

#include "fast_qs_module.h"

class EuclidianClass
{
    [...]
};

std::vector<double> get_euclidian_distances_to_reference(std::vector<std::vector<double>> unlabeled, std::vector<double> reference)
{
    EuclidianClass runner(unlabeled, reference);
    return runner.get_euclidian_result();
}
```

The other cpp file:

```
#include [...]

#include "fast_qs_module.h"

class CosineClass
{
     [...]
};

std::vector<double> get_dwds_distances(std::vector<std::vector<double>> unlabeled, std::vector<std::vector<double>> labeled, double alpha)
{
    CosineClass runner(unlabeled, labeled, alpha);
    return runner.get_dwds_result();
}
```

When I pack it all in one cpp it works, but why doesn't it work with two cpp files? The header is include guarded...

The error I am getting:

```
 compiler_compat/ld: build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/euclidian.o: in function `PyInit_fast_cosine':
    euclidian.cpp:(.text+0x810): multiple definition of `PyInit_fast_cosine'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/cdist_cosine.o:cdist_cosine.cpp:(.text+0xfc0): first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As per https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-reduce-the-build-time I split it like this:

Header:

```
void init_dwds(py::module_ &);
void init_euclidian(py::module_ &);

PYBIND11_MODULE(fast_cosine, mod) {
    init_dwds(mod);
    init_euclidian(mod);
}
```

Source files:

```
std::vector<double> get_dwds_distances(std::vector<std::vector<double>> unlabeled, std::vector<std::vector<double>> labeled, double alpha)
{
    CosineClass runner(unlabeled, labeled, alpha);
    return runner.get_dwds_result();
}

void init_dwds(py::module_ &mod)
{
    mod.def("get_dwds_distances", &get_dwds_distances, "Multithreaded DWDS calculations to get the values for each unlabeled sample.");
}
```

Source 2:

```
std::vector<double> get_euclidian_distances_to_reference(std::vector<std::vector<double>> unlabeled, std::vector<double> reference)
{
    EuclidianClass runner(unlabeled, reference);
    return runner.get_euclidian_result();
}

void init_euclidian(py::module_ &mod)
{
    mod.def("get_euclidian_distances", &get_euclidian_distances_to_reference, "Multithreaded Euclidian distance calculations to get the values for each unlabeled sample.");
}
```

but I still get

```
euclidian.cpp:(.text+0x810): multiple definition of `PyInit_fast_cosine'; build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/cdist_cosine.o:cdist_cosine.cpp:(.text+0xfc0): first defined here
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include guard only protects a header to be included more than once in a single translation unit. It does not help if a header contains something that needs not be placed in the header.

In your case, it looks like `PYBIND11_MODULE` expands to something like a definition rather than a declaration, which should not be in a header. Placing it in a `cpp` should solve.

Comment: Yeah, thats what it boiled down to. I kept it in the header, but did not include the header, and then it worked. Not entirely sure what it did, but renaming to cpp would have helped as well. Thanks!